# BoxConstraints forces an infinite height when streching containers

Tags: android-layout, flutter, flutter-layout

I am new to Android development. I am trying to stretch, 3 containers vertically and 3 containers horizontally using the row and column widget. Every time I add `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,`inside my Row widget I get a **BoxConstraints force an infinite height** error.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Multichild Container Test'),
        ),
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Container(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        width: 60.0,
                        height: 100.0,
                        child: Text('Container 1'),
                        color: Colors.pink.shade900,
                      ),

                      Container(
                        width: 60.0,
                        height: 100.0,
                        child: Text('Container 1'),
                        color: Colors.green.shade900,
                      ),

                      Container(
                        width: 60.0,
                        height: 100.0,
                        child: Text('Container 1'),
                        color: Colors.deepPurple.shade900,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),

                Container(
                  child: Row(
                    //crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        width: 60.0,
                        height: 100.0,
                        child: Text('Container 1'),
                        color: Colors.pink.shade900,
                      ),

                      Container(
                        width: 60.0,
                        height: 100.0,
                        child: Text('Container 1'),
                        color: Colors.green.shade900,
                      ),

                      Container(
                        width: 60.0,
                        height: 100.0,
                        child: Text('Container 1'),
                        color: Colors.deepPurple.shade900,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                )


              ],
            )
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use copy paste run full code below 
You can use `Expanded` and `flex` to provide height to `Container`
code snippet

```
Expanded(
            flex: 1,
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Multichild Container Test'),
        ),
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Container(
              child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: Container(
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        width: 60.0,
                        height: 100.0,
                        child: Text('Container 1'),
                        color: Colors.pink.shade900,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        width: 60.0,
                        height: 100.0,
                        child: Text('Container 1'),
                        color: Colors.green.shade900,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        width: 60.0,
                        height: 100.0,
                        child: Text('Container 1'),
                        color: Colors.deepPurple.shade900,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: Container(
                  child: Row(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        width: 60.0,
                        height: 100.0,
                        child: Text('Container 1'),
                        color: Colors.pink.shade900,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        width: 60.0,
                        height: 100.0,
                        child: Text('Container 1'),
                        color: Colors.green.shade900,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        width: 60.0,
                        height: 100.0,
                        child: Text('Container 1'),
                        color: Colors.deepPurple.shade900,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          )),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```